# python: How to generate a stub file from a built-in module at runtime?

Tags: python, stub

I'm able to import and use several modules in a specific python version, which are built-ins.

Is there some tool that could inspect these modules at run time and write stub files (.pyi) with the types (constants, classes, functions . . .)?

My final desire is to be able to write scripts with theses modules, using the intellisense of my IDE that can read these stub files.

I am aware o [stubgen](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html), but it requires the path of the files, which I don't have, because these modules are built-in of this specific python version.

I'm expecting a tool that could inspect the modules at run time in the python REPL. But any other approach that reaches the main objective would be good.